How to change layout of post types templates dynamically for separate posts?
I have created a post type in Elementor, but I want to make some changes in each separate post,eg, change the number of table rows and columns, loop grid content, archives content, etc ,how can I do it ?

You'll have to ask Elementor's development and support team about this - Elementor, while popular, isn't 'WordPress', it has it's own methods, rules, code, etc.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
